# Is there any jira rest api by which I get json of transitions of a particular ticket? Like when it goes from open-> in progress or any other state?

Tags: json, rest, url, jira, jira-rest-api

Is there any jira rest api by which I get JSON of all transitions of a particular ticket?

Like when it goes from 
            open-> in progress

Comment: Do you mean all of the possible transitions *or* all of the transitions it has already gone through?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using this request `GET /rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/transitions` you can see all the available transitions for the issue provided.